# Is it possible to paint without using a Frame of any sort in Java?

Tags: java, graphics, jframe, paint

I am wondering whether I am able to use the paint method of Java's graphics class on something other than a JFrame--that is, no JFrames allowed. Is it possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think a BufferedImage would work.  I didn't test that though.

Answer (score 0):

`Graphics` represents a graphic context, i.e. something you can draw on. In addition to GUI components like `JFrame`, `JPanel` etc. providing `getGraphics()` to access the visible gfx context, another common class that allows access to a gfx context is `BufferedImage` (or `Image` classes in general).

While painting on a visible GUI element immediately shows the results of the painting, using a `BufferedImage` allows you to perform the painting off screen into a buffer, and then painting the whole image at once (on a `JFrame` as you still need something visible) when you're ready to display the image. This is often used in animation and games when you need to avoid flickering for example.